# adding zustand to react app gives a compilation error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

This is the zustand part:

```
interface AuthSlice {
    user: User | null;
    session: Session | null;
    loginUser: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>
}


export const authStore = create<AuthSlice>((set, get) => ({
    user: null,
    session: null,
    loginUser: async (email: string, password: string) => {
        const {data, error} = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({email, password})
        console.log(data);
        set((state) => ({ user: data.user }));
        set((state) => ({ session: data.session }))
        if (error) throw error
    }
}));

export default authStore
```

and this is how it's used:

```
const Login: FC = () => {
  const Navigate = useNavigate();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  
  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { loginUser } = authStore()
    try {
      loginUser(event.currentTarget.email.value, event.currentTarget.password.value)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
    ...
    ...
    <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                autoFocus
              />
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                label="Remember me"
              />
              <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
              >
                Sign In
              </Button>
      </Box>
  )
```

and this is the error I get:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactNode'.
  Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.
     5 |
     6 | ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  >  7 |   <React.StrictMode>
       |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  8 |     <App />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  9 |   </React.StrictMode>,
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    10 | );
    11 |
```

and when I try to login (enter email and password), click on login button, I get this error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

not sure what did I miss with zustand setup.
I was following the documentation from zustand

Comment: Likely you have @types/react @types/react-dom miss-configured, as a side note, try to remove `FC` since it’s now officially deprecated, and replace it with : JSX.Element annotation

Comment: yes, versions were misconfigured. now both are same and I still got the error.

Comment: You prolly can’t do `const { loginUser } = authStore()`, normally there is something like `const store = useStore()` and you can’t have it inside function body, only in component body

Comment: yes, I moved it outside the function body and the second error is gone. 
I am still clueless about the first error.

Comment: Well first one is typescript one, so likely something configured poorly… idk try remove node_modules, yarn.lock and do `yarn install`

Answer (score 1):

If your configurations are correct and still getting this error, you might want to add following options in in `tsconfig.json` to associate the react types with `react`. It had solved problem for me.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
    // other compiler options
  }
  // other options
}
```